# Can I get distilled water by boiling milk?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, physical-chemistry

I need to boil some leftover whey. Can I get distilled water from the boiling process?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because thisa is more suited to [cooking.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle: yes.

Water is the main volatile component in whey and by distillation you can separate the water from the rest of the whey.

However, if there are some volatile components in the whey, distillation may not separate these from the water.

Moreover, [mechanical entrainment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entrainment_(engineering)) can also carry over some non-aqueous material, non-volatile, further reducing the purity of the distilled water.

Because of this and depending on the required purity of the distilled water, it may be necessary to carry out a two-stage distillation or a [fractionated distillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_distillation).

Comment: Thanks. very helpful. Any idea on the purity of the water?

Comment: Impossible to say. A 'smell and taste' test would tell you quite a bit, w/o expensive analysis. Also simple tests like total solids (TDS) and pH would be informative.

Comment: Upvote? :-) Thank you.

Comment: New here. Need 5 more reputation points to upvote. These same problems may be applicable for preparing distilled water using tap water.  So distilling plain water and whey shouldn't be too different (unless whey contains a lot more volatile components than water).

Comment: Thanks for the approval!